# Lose of global data sometimes inside promise chain nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

Data is lost while using promise chain.

Basically, I have 4 promise based functions which all are running in a loop nearly for 15000 iterations, All 4 functions are running as a resolve function after the previous promise function is resolved.

**Flow of my code**

1. Get the `max_id` from my database for understanding the no. of iterations(basically total movies in my database).
2. call the function `getMovie()` with the parameter `movie_id`, process data from database and save data in `movie_data`(movie_data is my final response from all promise) and save data in `film_basic_detail_db_resp` variable because some processing needs to be done within my other function i.e.`otherMovieDetailsSync`
3. After the resolve of `getMovie()`, call `getCastCrewArray()` with the parameter `movie_id`
4. Inside `getCastCrewArray` some processing on my new data and save it in `movie_data`, no relation to data coming from `getMovie()` i.e. `film_basic_detail_db_resp`
5. After resolve of `getCastCrewArray` call `getFilmCreditArray` with `movie_id`, process some data and save it in `movie_data` obj, no processing on `film_basic_detail_db_resp`.
6. After resolve of `getFilmCreditArray` call `otherMovieDetailsSync()` with the parameter `movie_id`, here I have used  the variable `film_basic_detail_db_resp` which I have set it in `getMovie()`

**The Issue**

Many times I am not getting the data saved inside `film_basic_detail_db_resp` in `otherMovieDetailsSync` function, I don't know why it is happening, tried many things, nothing is working.

What is wrong with my code?

### **My actual code**

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var qryBldr = require("../base/querybuilder");  

var no_data = true;
var film_basic_detail_db_resp = {};

release_date = ""; 
movie_data = {
    "data":{
        "mainContainerData":{

        }
    }

};

function getFilmCreditArray(movie_id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var sp_params = [
            movie_id
        ]

    resp_obj = {}
    resp_obj["credits"] = []
    credit_obj = {
        // "credit type":[]
    }
    data_val_arr = []
    qryBldr.callProcedure('GET_FILM_CREDIT', sp_params,function(err,db) {
        try
            {
                credit_obj = []
                db.forEach(function(elem,i) {
                    // process data from my db result
                    // save it into credit_obj
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(credit_obj));

                });

                // save data in my movie_data
                movie_data["data"]["mainContainerData"].push(credit_obj);
                resolve(movie_id);
            }
        catch(err){
            reject(err);
        }

    });

    });
}

function otherMovieDetailsSync(movie_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        // processing and using the film_basic_detail_db_resp global variable which i saved at getMovie() for further processing
        // save data to movie_data obj
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(movie_data));
        film_basic_detail_db_resp = undefined; // some dummy value after the processing is done
        resolve(movie_data);

    })
}


function getCastCrewArray(movie_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var sp_params = [
        movie_id
    ]
    resp = [];
    cast_crew_rows = [];
    crew_data_val_array = [];
    crew_parsing_obj = {};
    qryBldr.callProcedure('GET_FILM_CAST', sp_params,function(err,db) {
            try{
                // console.log(err);
                // console.log(db);
                db.forEach(function(elem,i) {

                    // process data from db and put them into cast_crew_rows,crew_data_val_array,crew_parsing_obj
                });


                // save data to movie_data
                movie_data["data"]["mainContainerData"].push({
                    "type" : "multiple_column_table_1",
                    "data" : {
                        "isDataHeaderAvailable" : true,
                        "dataValues" : cast_crew_rows    
                    }
                }); 
            }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log("err");
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(movie_id);
    });
})
}


function getMovie(movie_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        no_data = true;
        qryBldr.callProcedure('GET_FILM_DETAILS', [movie_id], function(err, data) { // call to my stoored procedure and getting response from db
            // console.log(err);
            // film_basic_detail_db_resp = data;
            // console.log(film_basic_detail_db_resp);
            data.forEach(function(elem) {

                // console.log(film_basic_detail_db_resp);

                // process results and put data in a global variable film_basic_detail_db_resp, because i want to use it in another function i.e. otherMovieDetailsSync
                no_data = false;
                film_basic_detail_db_resp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(elem)); // copying data  into variblae

                // fetching data from elem variable for further processing

                // saving data ro movie_data obj, which is my another global variable


                movie_data["data"]["mainContainerData"].push({
                    "type" : "table_without_border_1",
                    "data" : {
                        "dataValues" : box_ofc_data_val_arra,
                        "isNameAvailable" : true,
                        "name" : "Details"
                        }
                    })

            resolve(movie_id);
            });
        });
    });
}



/*getCastCrewArray(1)
.then(function(id) {
            console.log("success obj");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(movie_data));    
        })*/

function onMovieSuccess(md) {
    // console.log("inside success");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(md));
    return movie_data
}

// for(var i = 1; i<900;i++)
//  {getMovie(i)
//  // .then(getCastCrewArray)
//  // .then(getFilmCreditArray)
//  .then(otherMovieDetailsSync)
//  .then(
//          onMovieSuccess,
//          function() { console.log("rejected"); }
//      )
//  .catch(function(e) {
//      console.log(e);
//  })}

module.exports = {
    getMovie:getMovie,
    getCastCrewArray:getCastCrewArray,
    getFilmCreditArray:getFilmCreditArray,
    otherMovieDetailsSync:otherMovieDetailsSync
}
```

---

**Calling of my code**

```
function syncAllMovies(currentIterationID, maxIterationID){
if (maxIterationID == 0)
{
    qryBldr.callProcedure('GET_MAX_FILM_ID', [], function(err, data) {
        maxIterationID = data[0].max_id;
        syncMovie.getMovie(currentIterationID)
        .then(syncMovie.getCastCrewArray)
        .then(syncMovie.getFilmCreditArray)
        .then(syncMovie.otherMovieDetailsSync)
        .then(
                function(movie_data) {

                        mongoOBJ.getMongoDBObject(function(err, db) {
                            if(err)
                                console.log(err);


                                db.collection("<collection_name>").save(movie_data, function(err, res) {
                                    if (currentIterationID + 1 <= maxIterationID)
                                    {
                                        syncAllMovies(currentIterationID + 1, maxIterationID);
                                    }
                            });
                        })
                    },
                function() {
                    console.log("rejected");
                    if (currentIterationID + 1 <= maxIterationID)
                                {
                                    console.log("deleted");
                                    syncAllMovies(currentIterationID + 1, maxIterationID);
                                }
                }
            )
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
    });
}
else
{
    syncMovie.getMovie(currentIterationID)
    .then(syncMovie.getCastCrewArray)
    .then(syncMovie.getFilmCreditArray)
    .then(syncMovie.otherMovieDetailsSync)
    .then(
            function(movie_data) {
                    mongoOBJ.getMongoDBObject(function(err, db) {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err);
                            db.collection("<collection_name>").save(movie_data, function(err, res) {
                                if (currentIterationID + 1 <= maxIterationID)
                                {
                                    syncAllMovies(currentIterationID + 1, maxIterationID);
                                }
                                db.close();
                            });

                },
            function(obj) {
                console.log(obj);
                if (currentIterationID + 1 <= maxIterationID)
                                {
                                    console.log("deleted");
                                    syncAllMovies(currentIterationID + 1, maxIterationID);
                                }
            }
        )
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
}

syncAllMovies(1, 0);
```

---

It's a long code of 1200 lines, i cut it out for explaing, please feel free to ask, if you have any confusion.

Comment: `film_basic_detail_db_resp` is set to `undefined` in asynchronous code. How are you waiting for the asynchronous completion of the entire `getMovie` promise chain before performing another iteration for a different movie?

Comment: @traktor53  I used recursion for waiting for the promise chain, `film_basic_detail_db_resp` I set it to `undefined` after all my data( basically in the last function after fetching all data from it)

Comment: @traktor53 Moreover, I am getting `{}` not `undefined` in `film_basic_detail_db_resp`.

Comment: @traktor53 I added my recursive function as well, have a look.

Comment: To debug this I would remove the global variables and pass an object down the promise chain, one property of which is `movie_id`. I would also explicitly check that the 'GET_FILM_DETAILS' callback `data` argument has a length of one, and review use of the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...` construction. Without hands on debugging it is difficult if not impossible to comment further.